# SQL QUERY ERROR GROUPING A VIRTUAL TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm trying to do a JOIN with two table grouped by the same ID to get week and month results.

When I try to execute the query, SQL Server returns the following message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'P.WEEK' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the query:

```
Select 
    C.[id],
    P.[WEEK],
    SUM(C.[value1]+C.[value2]) AS MONTH
FROM  
    [Schema].[table] C
JOIN
    (Select 
        R.[Equipo],
        SUM(R.[value1]+R.[value2]) AS WEEK
     FROM
        [Schema].[Table] R
     WHERE
        R.[Horario]='TODO EL DIA'
        AND R.[date] BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, -8, GETDATE()),120) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),120)
     GROUP BY R.[id]) P ON C.[id] = P.[id]
WHERE
    C.[date] BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, -32, GETDATE()),120) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),120)
    AND C.[Horario]='TODO EL DIA'
GROUP BY 
    C.[id]
```

WHY? When I do this in MySQL the query returns the correct values.

Comment: For every column not in an aggregate function you must add in in the `GROUP BY` clause, i.e. Try Adding `P.[Week]` in `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: i dont understand why... but noww my query is ok. So many thanks mate!

Comment: My pleasure =). See if this article helps: [SQL: GROUP BY CLAUSE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

Comment: "*in MySQL the query returns the correct values*" I doubt that: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: is not the same example...